# Arc length of deltoid results in different values between integral bounds

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

when computing the arc length for the deltoid as found here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Arc_of_Deltoid

does anyone know why it is that computing the entire arc length from 0-2pi doesn't get the correct answer?  I get 16b/3 when using those bounds rather than the way the example does it with 3 * 2pi/3 resulting in 16b. Seeing as it is a function of θ where both dx and dy are squared in the equation for ds, why wouldn't it be of no consequence whether these values were positive or negative?

Thank you,

John

Comment: The square root turns it back into a function that can be positive or negative

Comment: Try to evaluate $1+2\cos \theta$ and $\sqrt{(1+2\cos \theta)^2}$ for $\theta=\pi$

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense.  I'll have to be careful with that.  Thanks for the response.